# cannot generate pdf with tcpdf

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf

on my site a user can print (in pdf) the nda he accepted
for some reason i cannot display the pdf

here the logic

first rewrite the rule

```
.htaccess
RewriteRule ^nda/?$ ndapdf.php?useSessionUser=1 [L]
```

then the php

```
<?php

$html = file_get_contents("/lib/nda.txt");
$html = str_replace("##user##", $_SESSION["currentUser"]);
$html = str_replace("##date##", date("Y-m-d h:i:s"));

require("/lib/web/tcpdf/config/lang/eng.php");
require("/lib/web/tcpdf/tcpdf.php");
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, "UTF-8", false);
$pdf->SetCreator("mysite");
$pdf->SetAuthor("author_name");
$pdf->SetTitle("NDA");
$pdf->SetSubject("Accepted NDA");

$pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, "", PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));
$pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, "", PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));

$pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);
$pdf->setLanguageArray(array("w_page" => ""));
$fontname = $p->addTTFfont("/fonts/AveriaSans-light.ttf", "TrueTypeUnicode", "", 32);
$pdf->SetFont("arial", "", 10);
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, "");
$pdf->lastPage();

$pdf->Output("/home/comp/pdf/nda/$currentUser.pdf", "F");
header("Content-Type: application/pdf\n");
read("/home/comp/pdf/nda/$currentUser.pdf");
```

i get:

**"TCPDF ERROR: Could not include font definition file: AveriaSans-light"**

the font is: ll /fonts/

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  85084 2011-11-02 17:51 AveriaSans-Light.ttf
```

thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think the problem is, that the directories `cache` and `fonts` of TCPDF (residing in the folder which path is stored in the constant `K_PATH_MAIN`, by default this is the TCPDF-directory) are not writeable by your webserver. Don't confuse your own `fonts`-directory with the one used by TCPDF internally.

The `fonts` directory has to be writeable because `addTTFfont` first converts the TTF-file and writes the output of the conversion in to the `fonts` directory. If later on `SetFont` is used with "AveriaSans-light" it tries to include those files and fails with "Could not include font definition file" if they are not found.

Answer (score 2):

vstm is right but also maybe because you have

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  85084 2011-11-02 17:51 AveriaSans-Light.ttf
```

with **capital L** and in your code is **lowercase l**